# Why do Coderbyte.com's Javascript templates like to return the original argument for the function?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing the "easy" programming challenges on Coderbyte.com ([full link here](http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/Challenges/))

The templates that coderbyte.com provides always looks something like this:

```
function DivisionStringified(num1,num2) {     
  // code goes here  
  return num1 + num2;              
}
```

My question is, why do they always return the arguments (eg. num1 + num2) which are the original inputs to the function? Can't you just define a new output variable to return? Is this a JavaScript convention?

Comment: It's no convention, just personal taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, why do they always return the arguments (eg. num1 + num2) which are the originally inputs to the function?

I would suspect it's so that the output starts off just showing the input value.

> Can't you just define a new output variable to return?

Of course you can, but what new output variable would they be defining in this case?

> Is this a JavaScript convention?

No, it's not. If you look, you'll see that they're doing this with most of the other languages as well. The value returned from a function should be whatever the function is supposed to return.